# Configure Tomcat for Different Applications

Tags: tomcat, configuration

I have an application that I can have multiple instances of that depend on different params. I would like to be able to run the same war file (under two different names of course) with different sets of these parameters. So basically I just want to pick a different spot on the file system to read from and have the apps know their "spot" on the file system.

I tried by adding my own `<appname>.xml` file in the `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost` directory with the contents...

```
<Context>
    <Parameter name="config.dir" value="/path/to/config/dir" override="false"/>
</Context>
```

And then I read that param from within Tomcat via ..

```
request.getServletContext().getInitParameter("config.dir");
```

But that only works when addressing as localhost. As soon as you address it via other aliases (such as http://my.server.com) that param is not read. What is the proper way to get a parameter into tomcat based on its application name but independent of its hostname?

I am using Tomcat 8

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [virtual hosting](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html) will be helpful.

Comment: Nope, don't see how this helps my situation at all. Maybe you can suggest how you think this addresses my issue?